# Translation/proof of elementary argument of Chebyshev

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, proof-writing

My question is whether the following proof is correct and how it might be better presented. This was an exercise to translate/shorten Chebyshev's argument that

$\hspace{80mm} (1)$

$\hspace{55mm}\log [x]! =$
$$
\begin{Bmatrix} 
+ ~\theta(x)~~~ +~~~\theta(x)^{1/2}~~~+\theta(x)^{1/3}~~+ ~~...etc.\\ 
+ ~\theta(x/2)+\theta(x/2)^{1/2}+\theta(x/2)^{1/3}+...etc\\
+ ~\theta(x/3)+\theta(x/3)^{1/2}+\theta(x/3)^{1/3}+...etc.\\ 
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

in which $\theta(x) = \sum_{p\leq x} \log p.$

**Chebyhev's discussion.** 
He mentions that $\theta(x)$ is zero for $x< 2,$  and by [x] he means $\lfloor x \rfloor.$ Writing $\psi(x) = \theta(x)+ \theta(x^{1/2})+ \theta(x^{1/3})...,$ and $T(x) = \log 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot...\cdot[x],$ he re-cast (1) as
$$\psi(x) + \psi(x/2)+ \psi(x/3)... = T(x). $$ 
He notes that both sides of (1) are comprised of terms $k\log a$ in which $a$ is a prime number and $k$ a whole number. For each $a$ on the r.h.s. above, $k$ will be equal to the number of terms of the sequence: 
$$
\begin{Bmatrix} 
~~~~x,~~~~~(x)^{1/2},~~~~~(x)^{1/3},...etc.\\ 
(x/2),(x/2)^{1/2},(x/2)^{1/3},...etc\\
(x/3),(x/3)^{1/2},(x/3)^{1/3},...etc.\\ 
\end{Bmatrix}
$$
which are not less than $a.$ For the left-hand side of the equation k will be equal for each term $k\log a$ to the highest power of $a$ dividing $1\cdot2\cdot 3\cdot...\cdot[x].$

**L1.** For n = 1,2,3,..., the number of terms of the sequence $(x)^{1/n},(\frac{x}{2})^{1/n},...,$ etc., which are not less than $a$ is equal to the number of $1,2,3,...,[x]$ divisible by $a^n.$

Proof of L1. Let $(\frac{x}{m+1})^{1/n} <a < (\frac{x}{m})^{1/n}< (\frac{x}{(m-1)})^{1/n}< (\frac{x}{(m-2)})^{1/n},...$ Then $a^n m < x, a^n (m-1)< x, a^n (m-2) < x, ... ,$ etc., are each elements of the sequence $1,2,3,...,[x].$

For an element of $1,2,3,...,[x]$ equal to $m a^n$ for some number $m$ we have $m a^n \leq x $ and $a \leq (\frac{x}{m})^{1/n}$ which is thus a member of the sequence above not less than $a.$

**L2.** The sum of the number of elements of $1,2,...,[x]$ divisible by $a, a^2, a^3,..., $ respectively, is equal to the highest power of $a $ dividing $[x]!$

Proof of L2. Consider the elements of $1,2,3,...[x]$ divisible by powers of $a.$ We count $k_1$ elements divisible by $a; ~k_2$ elements divisible by $a^2$ which will re-count elements divisible by $a;$ we count $k_3$ elements divisible by $a^3$ which will re-count elements divisible by $a$ and $a^2,$  and so on.

If there are $r$ distinct powers of $a$ contained in the elements $1,2,3,...,[x],$ we will have $k_1$ elements divisible by $a,$ $k_2 $ elements divisible by $a, a^2,$ ..., and $k_r $ elements divisible by $a, a^2,..., a^r.$ The total will be $k_1+k_2+ k_3+ ... + k_r $ which is precisely the highest power of $a$ dividing $[x]!$

So by L1, L2, for each prime $a$ the coefficient $k$ is the same on both sides of (1), hence the two sides are equal.