# Analytic Number Theory: Problem in Bertrand’s postulate

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I am trying to learn Bertrand’s postulate. I can not understand two steps

1. Why $\displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x}\log n=\sum_{e \leq x} \psi\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)$, 
   where $\psi(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{p^\alpha \leq x, \alpha \geq 1}\log p$?
2. $\displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x}\log n- 2\displaystyle\sum_{n \leq x/2}\log n\leq \psi(x)-\psi(x/2)+\psi(x/3)$.

Will you kindly help me.

Comment: While your question works just as well on its own, I personally would be happy if you could link your source :)

Comment: for 1. you have to use sieving to show that $$\displaystyle n! = \prod_{p} p^{\lfloor n / p \rfloor + 2\lfloor n / p^2 \rfloor + 3\lfloor n / p^3 \rfloor + \ldots}$$ : how many $m \le n$  are divisible by $p$ ? and by $p^2$ ? ...

Comment: and for 2. you have to use the same sieving on ${2k \choose k }$ (with $k = x/2$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444636/translation-proof-of-elementary-argument-of-chebyshev) has an answer to the first part of your question. [Chebyshev's original proof](https://archive.org/stream/117744684_001#page/n65/mode/2up) is online and you don't have to rely on my translation of his argument. In case the link breaks, it is Vol. I of Chebyshev's Oeuvres, p. 49, Memoire Sur Les Nombres Premiers at p. 53.

For the second part, begin with

$\hspace{55mm}\log [x]! = \sum \log x =$
$$
\begin{Bmatrix} 
 ~\theta(x)~~~ +~~~\theta(x)^{1/2}~~~+\theta(x)^{1/3}~~+ ~~...\\ 
 +~\theta(x/2)+\theta(x/2)^{1/2}+\theta(x/2)^{1/3}+...\\
 +~\theta(x/3)+\theta(x/3)^{1/2}+\theta(x/3)^{1/3}+...\\ 
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

$=\psi(x)+\psi(x/2)+\psi(x/3)+...=\sum_{e\leq x}\psi(x/e),$

in which $\theta(x) = \sum_{p\leq x} \log p,$ and because it's easier to look at I put $\theta(x/3)^{1/2}$ for $\theta((x/3)^{1/2}).$

If this seems laborious it makes your second inequality obvious.

$\sum_{n\leq x} \log n - 2 \sum_{n\leq x/2} \log n = $
$$
\begin{Bmatrix} 
 ~\theta(x)~~~ +~~~\theta(x)^{1/2}~~~+\theta(x)^{1/3}~~+ ~~...\\ 
 +~\theta(x/2)+\theta(x/2)^{1/2}+\theta(x/2)^{1/3}+...\\
 +~\theta(x/3)+\theta(x/3)^{1/2}+\theta(x/3)^{1/3}+...\\ 
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

minus

$$
\begin{Bmatrix} 
 ~2 \theta(x/2)~~~ +~~~2\theta(x/2)^{1/2}~~~+2\theta(x/2)^{1/3}~~+ ~~...\\ 
 +~2\theta(x/4)+2\theta(x/4)^{1/2}+2\theta(x/4)^{1/3}+...\\
 +~2\theta(x/6)+2\theta(x/6)^{1/2}+2\theta(x/6)^{1/3}+...\\ 
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

which is equal to

$$A=
\begin{Bmatrix} 
 ~\theta(x)~~~ +~~~\theta(x)^{1/2}~~~+\theta(x)^{1/3}~~+ ~~...\\ 
- ~\theta(x/2)-\theta(x/2)^{1/2}-\theta(x/2)^{1/3}-...\\
+ ~\theta(x/3)+\theta(x/3)^{1/2}+\theta(x/3)^{1/3}+...\\ 
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

plus

$$B=
\begin{Bmatrix} 
- ~\theta(x/4)~~~ -~~~\theta(x/4)^{1/2}~~~-\theta(x/4)^{1/3}~~- ~~...\\ 
+ ~\theta(x/5)+\theta(x/5)^{1/2}+\theta(x/5)^{1/3}+...\\
- ~\theta(x/6)-\theta(x/6)^{1/2}-\theta(x/6)^{1/3}-...\\
+ ~\theta(x/7)+\theta(x/7)^{1/7}+\theta(x/7)^{1/3}+...\\
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Note that $A \leq \psi(x)-\psi(x/2)+\psi(x/3) .$  Then note that in B the subtracted row is always greater than the the subsequent added row, 
so that the sum $A+ B \leq  \psi(x)-\psi(x/2)+\psi(x/3).$